# RedBeanPhp ошибка- Uncaught [HY000] - SQLSTATE[HY000]:

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, framework, orm, redbeanphp

Запускаю добавление статьи в базу данных,а мне выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught [HY000] - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364
>   Field 'add_time' doesn't have a default value trace:
>    #0  D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(882):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('INSERT INTO `ne...', Array)
>    #1  D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(919):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('INSERT INTO `ne...', Array)
>    #2  D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(3547):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetOne('INSERT INTO `ne...', Array)
>    #3  D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(4976):
>   RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCell('INSERT INTO `ne...', Array, 0)
>    #4  D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(5103): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->insertRecord('news', Array,
>   Array)
>    #5 D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(7646):
>   RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->updateRecord('news', Array, 0)
>    #6 D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php(7233):
>   RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->storeBean(Obj in
>   D:\webserver\OpenServer\domains\muzzone.ua\function\rb.php on line 720

Вот код подключения к бд:

```
<?php
  require "rb.php";
  R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=muzzonebase',  'root', '' );

  session_start();

?>
```

Вот форма

```
<form action="function/adding.php" method="POST" id="add">
                        <p class="zagolovok">Форма добавления статьи</p>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="registrationinput" placeholder="Введите название статьи"><br>
                        <p class="text">Добавьте картинку для своей статьи</p>
                        <input type="file" name="image" value=""><br>
                        <textarea name="short_text" form="add" rows="100" cols="300" class="registrationinput" id="short_text" maxlength="900" placeholder="Введите короткий текст для стать который будет отображатся на главной странице!"></textarea><br>

                        <textarea name="text" form="add"  cols="300" class="registrationinput" id="long_text" placeholder="Сдесь введите текст статьи"></textarea><br>
                        <button type="submit" name="add_news" class="registrationbutton">Добавить статью</button>

                    </form>
```

А вот обработчик формы

```
<?php

require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;


if(isset($data['add_news'])) {
  if(trim($data['name'])=='') {
    $errors[]='Введите название статьи!';
  }
  if(trim($data["short_text"])=='') {
    $errors[]='Введите короткий текст для статьи!';
  }
  if(trim($data["text"])=='') {
    $errors[]='Введите текст для статьи!';
  }

  if(!empty($errors)){
    foreach($errors as $error){?>
       <div><?php echo $error;?></div><hr>
    <?php }
}else {
 $new = R::dispense ('news');
  $new->name = $data['name'];
  $new->shorttext = $data['short_text'];
  $new->text = $data['text'];
  $new->img = $data['image'];
  R::store($new);
  echo "Вы успешно добавили статью в базу даных";

}
}


?>
```

Ошибка выводится при нажатии на кнопку добавления.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так а чего тут не понятного ? вам же в ошибке пишет, что у поля add_time нет дефолтного значения, значит оно обязательное, добавьте его в свой insert или добавьте дефолтное значение (к примеру CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Раньше не нада было так делать.

Comment: Возможно была обновлена версия mysql, в любом случае описание выше поможет решить эту проблеиу